# Design of notification system

Tags: database-design, notifications

I need to design notification system for our self made ERP system, that will send notifications to users when different things happen. 
Current system is simple as it could be: If something happened (e.g user changed its phone number in user profile) will an email be send to an accountant. 
Here is some disadvantages:

1. if user changed something twice, accountant will receive two emails.
2. if user changed something at Saturday midnight, accountant will receive email at unreasonable time.

So,I need to design something with deferred sending (not always, some alerts will have to come immediately), solution also must be able to group message, so multiple messages may be send with one email.

My database design looks like that: 
[image: Database design]

Where event table contains predefined event text with placeholders, event_transport table defines available transport (email, SMS, push) and event_priority table contains priority rules (if an event may be send immediately, allowed, hours and so).

Believed workflow.
[image: workflow]

So, I need help with steps inside of red circle, I don't understand clearly how to implement it. Surely I will need a queue table that will contain all messages ready to sending. And here I stuck.

Any ideas how to implement priority and transport aware sending queue?

Thanks for attention.